# laptop fan weird behavior: very loud noise when working at high speed(rpm)

Tags: laptop-repair

My laptop fan gets a strange problem. When it turns with high rpm (e.g. when high load on CPU or when CPU is working for a while or just when I click fan dust extraction in Lenovo driver) it produces a very high noise.

I removed the fan, clean it from dust and put it in place again but no difference happened.

My laptop is Lenovo g4070 and it's fan is SUNON EG75080S2-C010-S9A.

Besides replacing fan with a new one, anyone knows the cause this very amazing problem?

Another question

If I go for buying a new one and there is no exact model of this fan present in the mall, can I use different models?with what considerations?

Thanks

Comment: google gives about 50,000 results for replacement fans, under 10USD, worldwide suppliers

Comment: Just because the fan has a very high noise, does not mean it's not functional, if the fan is running at a high RPM it means your usage requires that to happen to cool your device.  Using an improper fan in a laptop can result in thermal throttling problems.  You are better off with the noise.

Comment: Has the noise changed over time? Or is it just a loud fan?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere about a fellow who said oiling fans with a drop or two of light oil would quiet them, even for so-called "sealed fans", but that might not be the best/cleanest idea either

Comment: @Attie when I turn the laptop on, the fan is off. After windows starts, it turns on. After a while(20 mins roughly) it makes a very unusual loud noise.

Answer (score 0):

Some fans are louder than others.
I can't say if yours is defective, but SUNON fans are known to be loud.

For example, one answer on Ars Technica to the question of
[Sunon fans any good?](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1054989) says :

> They are on the loud side, and they are powerful. They are a good combo of power and noise, but they arent quiet. They also arent a Panaflo/Papst quailty. But definatly not BAD fans... just not the best.

Another [testimony](https://www.techspot.com/community/topics/a-very-loud-fan.65691/)
says "at 2 in the morning it wakes the whole street up", which might be an
exaggeration.

You may also compare the noise you are hearing to others of that manufacturer
on Youtube :
[Sunon Micro Fan - Noise Test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2ArLLLt27c)
and
[Sunon fan noise maglev](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYwkl0sepP8).

As you have fully verified the fan, perhaps it is working according to specs.